# 3D rotation for TextView not working on Jelly Bean (4.3)

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, textview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I get a strange issue with the rotationY method on Android Jelly Bean.

I animate a rotation, while the user moves his finger to the left/right side, a LinearLayout rotates on its Y axis.

Inside this LinearLayout there are two TextViews. These TextViews (better said the content of the TextViews) disappears (on screen), if I set a rotation value for the LinearLayout.

The same issue appears if I try only to rotate the TextViews.

The rotation works on Android phones with a version bigger 4.3 like a sharm.

Here are screenshots of the explained issue.

*Before rotating*

[image: Before rotating]

*After rotating*

[image: After rotating]

The code is very simple:

```
void rotate container(float rotate){
    container.setRotationY(rotate);
}
```

The Ui:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    style="@style/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="16dp"/>

<TextView
    style="@style/body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I hope some one can help me :) .